# How to hide jitsi watermark in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jitsi, jitsi-meet

i'm using [react-jitsi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jitsi) library for rendering jitsi video

```
var interfaceConfig = {
   SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK: true,
   SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: false,
};

<Jitsi
      // doamin="meet.jit.si"
      roomName={'12345rfewhgresjttyi'}
      displayName={'prakash'}
      password={password}
      interfaceConfig={interfaceConfig}
    />
```

i tried to hide jisti watermark in background using interfaceConfig.  but interface config doesn't affect any UI.

Also i tried with css:

```
.leftwatermark {
  display: none;
}
```

This is also not working.

i referred [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/interface_config.js) link for hide watermark

Is there any way to hide the jitsi watermark using reactjs?

Comment: i would try to find the exact classname of the parent container of the watermark and add this: `.theclassname { visibility:hidden; display: none; opacity: 0; }`

Comment: .largeVideoContainer .watermark .leftwatermark this the parent class but css doesn't affect anything

Comment: if it's embedded in the video, i dont think there is a way to remove it

Comment: Remove the file in the server. Is /usr/share/jitsi-meet/images/watermark.png

Answer (score 5):

SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK and SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS can **not** be overwrite by the **client** and **must be in the server config**

You must edit the file interface_config.js

```
sudo nano /usr/share/jitsi-meet/interface_config.js
```

And switch to

- SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK: false,
- SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: false,

then, save your file, and restart your browser page.

Be careful, this file can be reset to default when your upgrade Jitsi on your server. The fix is already asked in the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

there is no any way of removing the jitsi watermark.
but you can remove the link behind it.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the background-image link in css like below

```
.leftwatermark {
left: 32px;
top: 32px;
background-position: center left;

background-image: url(your-image-url); } // better view
```

Comment: You can't change css of an iframe from an outside parent. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide the watermark of the Jitsi meet by using `iFrame API`, what you have to do is to override these attributes which include in the `interface_config.js`

```
SHOW_JITSI_WATERMARK: false,
HIDE_DEEP_LINKING_LOGO: true,
SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK: false,
SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: false

const options = {
    ...
    configOverwrite: { startWithAudioMuted: true },
    interfaceConfigOverwrite: { DISABLE_DOMINANT_SPEAKER_INDICATOR: true },
    ...
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```